# Create SEO Friendly URLs from _GET query

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I have a search form using GET request. When I hit enter, the url is as usual not SEO friendly, is there a way in which I can make it display SEO friendly urls when entered?

Eg.

> GET Request http://someurl.com?a=search&query=what+are+you+looking+for
>     SEO URL should be http://someurl.com/search/what+are+you+looking+for

I already created a rule

```
RewriteRule ^search/(\w+) index.php?a=search&query=$1
```

in my .htaccess that works when I manually type the SEO Url into the address bar. So I guess it's only a matter of making sure when I hit enter inside the search field, it loads the SEO Url instead of the other.

Comment: You will have to use Javascript to construct the URL you want and "submit" your search form that way, or you issue a redirect from your server to the desired URL.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using GET variables in this case; it is much more "correct" than adding the query to the URL. Also why on earth would you want to SEO a search result page? Search engines probably go out of their way *not* to index/rank search result pages. They contain different content every time you visit them, so they would be seen as useless to search engines. Something like `.../search?query=abc` would be fine.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen makes sense! But if I want to share the search link with someone, all that string defeats the purpose of SEO friendly urls.

Comment: SEO has very little to do with link sharing. Search result pages will change depending on the content on the website, so sharing it will probably not be very useful. You would normally share the direct link to the content of interest. When it comes to URLs, SEO is about [making the URL canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element), so search engines can better rely on them.

Comment: right but this isn't a search page result. This is just pulling data from a db based on keywords. So I would like to say bookmark a keyword eg http://something.com/search/keyword so that when I perform the search I won't have to type the keyword again, just paste the link and I get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redirect your orignal uri to the new uri , add the followng before your existing rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?a=search&query=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: thanxx changes the url as requested but I can't pick the variable. As in the $a and $q variables. Also is there a way to work with this locally? I can't get that done unless I upload onto the server

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `I can't pick The variable` ?

Comment: as in the $a and $query variable. How do I retrieve what is searched for. It just changes the URL but the variables can't be retrieved.

Comment: How are you retrieving Get variables?

Comment: With this rule I can retrieve Get variables on php page like this `$_GET["a"];`

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the 'add the following before' I simply deleted the original and pasted yours. It works now. Awesome. Thanxxx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?a=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

This will leave you with the URL:

`http://someurl.com/search/what+are+you+looking+for`

Answer (score 0):

I do this on my way :)

**This is the form for search**

```
  <form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search"/>
  </form>
```

**Before form**

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
echo '<script>window.location = "www.domain.com/search/'.$_POST['search'].'"</script>';
}
```

**And in `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=search&search=$1 [NC,L]
```